# How do I increment a Integer in Java?

Tags: java, integer

I want increment a integer in java, l create this method

```
private Integer id;
private Integer operationId;
// getter and setter id, operationId
public void increment() {
    if (operationId != null) {
     id= new Integer(id.intValue() + 1);
    }
}
```

but don't work can someone helpe me?

Comment: Are `operationId` and `id` meant as two different things?

Comment: What’s `operationId`?

Comment: You need to initialize id and operationId with some value.

Comment: operation Id is Integer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    private Integer id=new Integer(0); //
public void increment() {
 if (operationId != null) { 
id= new Integer(id.intValue() + 1);
 } 
}
```

Comment: It's work thank youuuuu